# OSError: Directory not empty raised, how to fix?

Tags: python, file, exception, directory, rename

I'm just trying to write a little application that takes a value from a file named 'DATA.DAT' and renames the folder which contains that file with that value.

The .py script runs in another folder and allows the user to define the path. To give you a better idea, the user defined path must be like (on a mac) '/Users/User/Desktop/FOLDER' and 'FOLDER' should contain 'DATA.DAT'.

That's how a little part of the source code looks like:

```
try:
    data = open('DATA.DAT').read()

    data_data = data[12:17]
    path_paths = path.rsplit('/')
    basepath = '/'.join(path_paths[:-1])
    chdir(basepath)

    if path_paths[-1] <> data_data:
        rename(path_paths[-1], data_data)
        raw_input('Folder name has been corrected! Thank you.')
        quit()
    else:
        print('Folder name was already correct! Thank you.')
        quit()
except IndexError:
    raw_input('ERROR!')
    quit()
```

Well, it works; but it raise and exception when 'FOLDER' contains more than one file (actually, 'FOLDER' should contain just 'DATA.DAT' and other folders. That doesn't give problems.)...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Desktop/example.py", line 72, in <module>
    rename(path_paths[-1], data_data)
OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty
```

Just to prevent that this happens, is there a way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you chdir() out of the directory before renaming it?  What platform is this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit:** The right tool is [`shutil.move`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move):

```
shutil.move(path_paths[-1], data_data)
```

assuming `path_paths[-1]` is the absolute directory you want to rename, and `data_data` is the absolute directory name you want to rename it to.

The destination directory *must not already exist* for this to work. The two locations don't need to be on the same filesystem.

---

Old answer: Use [`os.renames`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.renames) instead of `os.rename`.

It will recursively create any needed directories.

Comment: I've tryed but it gives me exactly the same error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Desktop/example.py", line 72, in <module>
    renames(path_paths[-1], data_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 199, in renames
    rename(old, new)
OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty

Comment: Thank you, now it's working! Here an example:

path_paths[-1] = '/Users/User/Desktop/lol'
data_data = '/Users/User/Desktop/asd'

...am I right?

Comment: @PyGuy that looks right to me, as long as the `asd` directory doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to use [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html).

Answer (score 0):

Althoug a decade later.. is possible to replace the way for split path

```
path_paths = path.rsplit('/')
```

for

```
path_paths = os.path.split(path)[1]
```

And for renaming problem:

```
os.rename('myfolder/oldname', 'myfolder/newname')
```